# MPAndroidChart: How to create dual axis?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for drawing line chart.

I need to draw a Dual YAxis Line chart (i.e. with 2 Y Axis, one on left and other on right). But when I draw the graph it is being drawn from left. It takes into consideration the Left YAxis values rather than the Right YAxis values.

I am drawing Weights(kg) on right side and Heights(ft) on the left side.
As weights will be in terms of 40s, 50s etc and heights in terms of 5, 6 etc... The Line being drawn for Height takes left reference, which has 50s, 60s and hence never comes up.

Please let me know how to direct to draw considering the right Y Axis for Height rather than left Y Axis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use the `setAxisDependency` function in order to let a `DataSet` depend on a given axis. In your case it should be set to `right`:

```
LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(data, "Your Label");
set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT); // plot this set against the right axis
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved a lot of work for me. I owe you a treat :)